# Matching file paths regardless of network protocol

Tags: python, path, pattern-matching, network-protocols

I am developing a tool that deletes files on network paths based on several conditions. I would like to exclude certain paths from being checked and am having trouble finding a suitable method.

Some of the paths the program handles are as follows:

```
nfs_path = "nfs://Sharepoint/Path/to/Folder/File.ext"
smb_path = "smb://SERVER/Sharepoint/Path/to/Folder/File.ext"
afp_path = "afp://server/Sharepoint/Path/to/Folder/File.ext"
upnp_path = "upnp://277b787b-5b27-b46f-1687-91100ada8d1f/Path/to/Folder/File.ext"

exclusion = "smb://user:pass@server/E/Downloads/Path/to/Folder"
```

As you can see some of the paths use credentials, while others do not. These network paths should be able to be matched to one another.

In short, I would like to get confirmation that `File.ext`, using any protocol, is part of `Folder` (which I excluded from checking). Since I'm not an expert with path manipulation or regular expressions, I'm in a bind. I attempted the regex below, which fails for the NFS path since it takes the share name (`E`) too. It completely fails for the UPnP paths, because of their totally different nature.

```
"(?P<protocol>((smb|nfs|afp|upnp)://((.+:.+@)?.+?/)?))?(?P<directory>.+)"
```

I also tried using the `os.path` module, but the methods seem not suitable.

While waiting for an answer that is more efficient, I built a correctly parsing regex that will only capture the folder structure and ignore the prefix:

```
"(?:smb|afp|nfs|upnp)://(?:(?:.+):(?:.+)@)?(?:.+?)/(?P<tail>.*)$"
```

Could anyone point me in the direction of a more efficient approach? I think this will be too memory consuming to test for a lot of different files.

It needs to work on python 2.6 or lower, since it is an addon to an existing program.

Comment: Why do you single out NFS as taking the share name when smb and even local path also include the 'E'? Does it always have the E? Could you split on the first 'E' and take the rest of the string as the path, stripping an optional ':' in the beginning, to account for the local_path?

Comment: Only when I use the NFS as input for the regex, will it also eat the `E`. All other paths I mentioned work fine, because the regex assumed a server name, which NFS doesn't use.

The name of the share varies, as does the file name. The user selects a path to be excluded from checking. If there are files on that path, then they should not be deleted.

Comment: Have you seen `os.path.splitunc`? I'm not on Windows, so I can't test it.

Comment: Yes I have, those only work for UNC paths which are formatted like `\\Sharepoint\Path\to\Folder\File.ext`. All of the paths yield an empty mount point and the entire path as the relative path.

Comment: Unless someone comes along with a fantastic solution, I think your best bet is to extract the protocol name (easy in your examples) and then parse the rest of the string accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If your network and local directories are identical, you can use os.walk(local) to get the directories for network by simply changing your drive.

```
import os
networkdir = "Z:\\"
localdir = "C:\\"

for dirs,subdirs,files in os.walk(localdir):
    if os.path.join(localdir,dirs) == excluded:
        continue
    for filename in files:
        localfile = os.path.join(localdir,dirs,filename)
        networkfile = os.path.join(networkdir,dirs,filename)
```

To check if a file is in a folder that was excluded:

```
 excludedpath = "C:\excluded\"
 filename = "file.ext"
 os.path.exists(os.path.join(excludedpath,filename))
```

Comment: I forgot to add that the network paths will not always be mounted as a share. This is to create as much flexibility as possible. Also, I mistakenly added the requirement that local paths and network paths should be interchangable. This is not the case, and I have updated the question to reflect this. Only (unmounted) network paths, either with or without embedded credentials, have to be interchangable. I guess this invalidates the `os.walk` example you provided, for which I'm sorry.